# Zsh - How to source for the same name file inside subdirectories and exclude specific directories?

Tags: directory, zsh, subdirectory

```
for file in $LIB_DIR/*/config; do
source $file
done
```

I have to look up all the subdirectories that contain the `config` file, but  I want to exclude two specific directories from being read the same name `config` file.

Comment: Try `$LIB_DIR/^(dir1|dir2)/config`. This assumes the directories you want to exclude are immediately under the `$LIB_DIR` directory.  You will probably have to turn on extended globbing with `setopt extendedglob`.  More details are in the filename generation section of the `zshexpn` man page.

Comment: @Gairfowl Why don’t you write that as an answer? Now the question remains marked as “unanswered”.